# How do i add date limits to twitter sentiment analysis code? (Example : 1/9/2021 to 7/9/2021)

Tags: python, twitter, sentiment-analysis

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
    # input for term to be searched and how many tweets to search
    searchTerm = input("Enter Keyword/Tag to search about: ")
    NoOfTerms = int(input("Enter how many tweets to search: "))
    
    # searching for tweets
    self.tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=searchTerm, lang = "en").items(NoOfTerms)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not about sentiment analysis, but about using the `tweepy` API. So you should look into its docs.

This might help you: https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/client.html?highlight=query#search-tweets.

`Client.search_all_tweets` has the parameters `start_time` and `end_time`, which is probably what you are looking for.